# Classic ASP, Sending E-mail error '8004020f'

Tags: asp-classic

I am getting error, when I send a mail

> error '8004020f'
>   /sis/mail.asp, line 168

Here my code.

```
Set cdoConfig = Server.CreateObject( "CDO.Configuration")

cdoConfig.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
cdoConfig.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="mail.dartconsulting.info"
cdoConfig.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
cdoConfig.Fields.Update

Set cdoMessage = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Message")
Set cdoMessage.Configuration = cdoConfig
cdoMessage.From = "darteam28@gmail.com"

cdoMessage.To=email
cdoMessage.Subject = "Your  Password"
cdoMessage.HtmlBody = "<table><tr><td></td></tr>"&_
                "<tr><td colspan=2>Please find below your password</td></tr>"&_
                "<tr><td>Password :&nbsp;&nbsp;"&password&"</td></tr>"&_
                "<tr><td>UserName :&nbsp;&nbsp;"&uid&"</td></tr>"&_
                "<tr><td>EmailID :&nbsp;&nbsp;"&email&"</td></tr>"&_
                "<tr><td colspan=2>Please login and confirm/change your emailid</td></tr><table>"

cdoMessage.Send
Set cdoMessage = Nothing
Set cdoConfig = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't enough information in your post to solve the problem, as Vogel612 said. However, by far the most likely cause is that the server `mail.dartconsulting.info` requires authentication, while you are trying to send without authentication.

I have connected to this server from my local computer and it gave me `550 Authentication is required for relay`, so even if you're located on the same server there's a high likelihood that you also need to be authenticated.

Please refer to this website:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190905195123/http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp
(or do a web search) on how to send email with CDO with authentication.

Answer (score 4):

The system will produce an **error '8004020f'** on an invalid recipient email address.

In my case, the issue was related to an invalid email address with a space before the @ sign.

Comment: This was the issue I had too.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me: http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

```
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="remoteserver"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60


ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'End remote SMTP server configuration section==

ObjSendMail.To = "test@test.com"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "this is the subject"
ObjSendMail.From = "someone@someone.net"

' we are sending a text email.. simply switch the comments around to send an html email instead
'ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "this is the body"
ObjSendMail.TextBody = "this is the body"

ObjSendMail.Send

Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Make send using as 1 instead of 2

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue happened when we started sending bulk emails from the server.
I fixed it by trippeling the smtpconnectiontimeout, from 60 to 180.

I do not know if this is a good practice though, would appreciate feedback.