# error '8004020f' classic asp sending mail

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, cdo.message

email application will not send getting error below

error '8004020f'

```
Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "wpmssql1.worldispnetwork.com"
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMail.Subject="Your LaPineTrucks.com Password"
objMail.From="save@lapinetrucks.com"
objMail.To= Email
objMail.TextBody= Thank you
objMail.Send
set objMail=nothing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP, Sending E-mail error '8004020f'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289019/classic-asp-sending-e-mail-error-8004020f)

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the variable '`Email`' hold the return address?  If not then the line beginning `objMail.To=` to be `objMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"`
2. You need to put "Thank you" into quotes

I made those changes (above) and changed the server IP and it worked at treat.

I use the application [SMTP4DEV](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) to test email funcitonality, there are probably others.  You configure your server address to be '127.0.0.1' in your ASP code and all emails appear in this applicaiton; your real server won't be troubled.  This can be real handy if you accidentally send thousands of emails in error as I did once.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this same '8004020f' error.  It was due to switching web site from running standard to secure HTTP (HTTP to HTTPS).  Configuration.Fields.Item ...  functions required changing 
 from  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/..."
 to "https://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/..."